# desktop app gui design - best tool

Tags: mysql, windows, user-interface, powerpoint

i'm working on a project - an office information management system,
the database is a MySQL database, and now i have to build the front end GUI.
already I drawed a model of a screen example with PP (from total of 15 in my system),

my question is how to build the GUI? which tool/language is simple and easy to learn?
i thought about C++ but i no experience with it...

the information have to be retrived from the DB, read, write, queries, and so on.
will be happy to read your thoughts

![Powerpoint initial model][1]

Answer (score 3):

The implementation that should come to your mind is one in a programming language you know. You can program this in many languages:

- Visual Basic. If you already know it, this can be the fastest. Start the IDE and put together a forms project for you DB app.
- Java. Many people know Java and you can pick it up in a matter of days and you're likely to have use for it in several projects. A Swing or AWT project that you build in Eclipse or Netbeans with the DB driver for the DB connection will work.
- Python is also a popular choice. You can use the library [tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) to make quick GUIs.
- C/C++ will also work. But if you don't know C/C++ already you might want to build GUIs with higher abstraction.
- A web application with CSS/JScript using some Javascript framework to do DB i/o. But from your question it definitely seems that you want a desktop app.
- Use this project to learn a new language. You might not know Lua, Haskell, Clojure, Scala, Kotlin, Fantom, Erlang or some other tool that you don't know how to connect to MySQL with, then it'll be good practice to do so in a new language.

Any of the above will work and if I faced this project I would use tool of the above.

Comment: +1 for quote 'The implementation that should come to your mind is one in a programming language you know.' and +1 for 'Use this project to learn a new language', or enhance your already existing skills in your prefered programming langauge (eg maybe think about it as being a 'mobile' app, so as it could be easily converted to being so)